# My rabbit just had babies and isn’t feeding them

Tags: rabbits, feeding, junior-pets

So we just added 3 more rabbits (birth) to the place but our rabbit isn't feeding them. I've had to give them milk for the past week and a half. I've monitored the place with camera's but she's not feeding them at all. What can I do so that our rabbits can be fed so that I don't have to feed them or should I just keep feeding them until the mother rabbit decides to do something about it? (Different rabbit than the rabbits dying.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had two groups of babies back in 2003 and as with your case the mother never wanted to feed them, we had to hold her and then get the kittens around, i suppose its natural behaviour, but be careful because the mother will get angry & upset after some minutes and  can hurt the kittens with kicks.

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen recently, she was really young. Make sure that you have a nest for them to be in, I think this helps trigger her motherly instincts. Also if they are not being fed give them kitty replacement milk in a little bottle. The mother rabbit is really sneaky about feeding them so check their bellies and try not to disturb her if she is doing her motherly duties.

Comment: Also just an update, the ones that we got to before they were too skinny ended up surviving on kitty milk until their mother started to feed them.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Unfortunately they have died. I don't know what is the cause.

Because:

1. Rabbit had 2 year.
2. It was her 3rd birth.

Results:

1. Baby rabbits has died.

I have noticed:

1. Rabbit didn't pull off fur before giving birth.
2. Rabbit completely stopped doing labor.

My recommendation:

1. If you have more females, plan birth for both at the same time so if one mother abandon babies you can try giving them to other one.
2. Check if she pull off fur. If she's about to give birth and didn't pull off fur to make nest something must be wrong.
3. If you have technology like camera for streaming. Use it for non-stop/daily check on nest.
4. If mother moves too much and don't stay/lie near nest something is wrong and probably stopped doing labor.

It will be difficult for you to save them if she abandon them because they need milk with bioculture (germs) from mother. They also eat mother's excrements for this reason. So TRY TO PLAN pregnancy for 2 or more rabbits at same time.